# How to store formatted text in oracle table and load it back into json?

Tags: java, json, oracle, jackson, text-formatting

I want to store formatted text in oracle database. I don't about correct way of storing it but i have added html tags in text. Is there any in-built functionality in oracle by using which i can store rich text?

I am fetching this text in resultset and converting it to json.
I am trying to load above stored text in json but I am getting o/p like

```
{
   "text": "<p> my sample text..<br/>"
}
```

I don't want these tags to be shown in json.
 what should i do?

I am using jackson for json manipulation..

Comment: Take a look at regexp_replace function to remove all tag strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using regexp_replace function, example:

```
select regexp_replace('this <span> is <p> a test </br> test','\<[a-z]*\>|\<\/[a-z]*\>',null) from dual
```